# SPDT relay as SPST: why tie common to NC?

Tags: relay

I came across a circuit that switches line-connected heating coils using relays.  The relays are SPDT, and are connected as so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDvLKum.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Why connect the relay like so?  My intuition would be to just leave the NC contact open.  Is there some subtlety that I'm missing?

The only thing I could come up with is that connected these two leaves more room for thicker copper on the `LINE` trace.  Behold the relay's pinout:

[image: Relay pinout]

This way one could route a beefy trace through the NC and common (left and center, respectively) instead of slimming down at the common pins to avoid the NC ones.

Comment: I would say no reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could simply be layout, especially if it's this kind of relay:

[image]

If the relays are stacked close together a fatter trace may be possible if the PCB layout person runs the COM close to the N.C., in which case it should be connected if it is too close to safely withstand the expected voltages.

Comment: This was my thought, too, yet I cannot verify due to not having access to the layout or physical board.

Comment: Yes, that's possible with your relay type too. It's common to adjust the schematic to make the layout better.

Answer (score 2):

One reason would be this: floating nodes are bad, and can create problems (especially in a vacuum, the metal can reach any potential).

This rule also applies to inputs or amplifiers that are in a dual package (one amplifier or IC that is unused can cause problems by oscillating for example.)

But in this case it's probably irrelevant if it's tied to the line or not.